# Printing dictionary contents

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Pickaxes = {
 'adamant pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'bronze pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'dragon pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'inferno adze': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'iron pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'mithril pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'rune pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'steel pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5}}
```

This is the dictionary i created for a game, when entering the store the pickaxes will be printed on the screen to show the contents of the store. Is there any way i can have them printed from the dictionary showing the NAME of the axe and the PRICE also with the word COINS at the end like this.

ps. Please keep in mind that the user will choose what axe he wants through a raw_input which checks against the Dictionary Above such as if the user wanted a rune pickaxe they would type that in and it would check if it is in the dictionary i cannot add the price within the name of the axe itself.
    adamant pickaxe - 100 Coins

Comment: Do you want a function how to format the dictionary entries, or do you want us to write the entire store for you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ive tried adding the price to the name of the axe within the dictionary like this: Pickaxes {'adamant pickaxe - 100 coins'{cost: 100}} but this will change the name of the pickaxe within the dictionary.

Comment: i want to print something like that without having to add to the name of the pickaxe so maybe something like this: print Pickaxes['cost'] but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to know how to print the information about an axe, maybe the following code can help you understand what to do, but without more code of what you have tried, it will be hard to give you a working solution to your own problem:

```
>>> Pickaxes = {
 'adamant pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'bronze pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'dragon pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'inferno adze': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'iron pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'mithril pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'rune pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'steel pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5}}

>>> for axe, values in Pickaxes.items():
    print '{} - costs: {}, speed: {}'.format(axe, values['cost'], values['speed'])

bronze pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
mithril pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
adamant pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
steel pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
iron pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
rune pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
dragon pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
inferno adze - costs: 100, speed: 5
```

You could streamline this process like this:

```
>>> Pickaxes = {
 'adamant pickaxe': {'name': 'adamant pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'bronze pickaxe': {'name': 'bronze pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'dragon pickaxe': {'name': 'dragon pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'inferno adze': {'name': 'inferno pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'iron pickaxe': {'name': 'iron pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'mithril pickaxe': {'name': 'mithril pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'rune pickaxe': {'name': 'rune pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'steel pickaxe': {'name': 'steel pickaxe', 'cost': 100, 'speed': 5}}

>>> for axe in Pickaxes.values():
    print '{name} - costs: {cost}, speed: {speed}'.format(**axe)


bronze pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
mithril pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
adamant pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
steel pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
iron pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
rune pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
dragon pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
inferno pickaxe - costs: 100, speed: 5
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted! Thanks so much. if you could explain why you wrote for axe in Pickaxes.values(): and the .format(**axe) it would be great

Comment: You should read about [Python Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) And how [Python String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) works

Answer (score 2):

Tips:

- Use a format string to get a nice description:

  ```
  '{name}: {value} coins'.format(name='adamant pickaxe', value=100)
  ```
- iterate over Pickaxes.iteritems() to get all the elements:

  ```
  for name, properties in Pickaxes.iteritems():
      # do something with name and properties['cost']
  ```
- the [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function will help you to iterate over your pickaxes in a specific order.